# How can I print out the error in a Stored Procedure executed in a Snowflake Task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I used the suggested way from ChatGPT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
try {
  // code for stored procedure
} catch (err) {
  // print out error message
  var errorMsg = 'Error in stored procedure: ' + err.message;
  RAISE_ERROR(errorMsg, 1001);
}
$$;
```

And then I do:

```
select * from table(information_schema.task_history(
    scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('day',-7,current_timestamp()),
    result_limit => 100,
    task_name=>'TS_COMBI_REFRESH'))
order by scheduled_time;
```

I kept seeing this show up in the ERROR_MESSAGE column:

| Error_Message |
| --- |
| JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: RAISE_ERROR is not defined in TS_COMBI_REFRESH at ' RAISE_ERROR(errorMsg, 1001);' position 3 stackstrace: TS_COMBI_REFRESH line: 61 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table that catches the audit log of the Stored Procedure runs.

```
create or replace table return_values_sp (str varchar);
```

Create the Stored Procedure, and write the logs to the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TS_COMBI_REFRESH()
  RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE javascript
  execute as owner
  AS
  $$

  var logging = [];
  logging.push("SP started at: " + new Date().toLocaleString() )
  
  try
  {
    logging.push("\n Trying SP.");
    
    // Do something in SP

    logging.push("\n Successfully ran SP.");
  } 
  catch (err)
  {
    logging.push("\n " + JSON.stringify(err).replace(/["']/g, "") ); 
  }
  
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"insert into return_values_sp values('" + logging + "');"});
  var res = stmt.execute();
 
  return logging;
$$;
```

View the logs in that table. Copy paste the text to Notepad++ so that the newline characters are more visible.

```
SELECT * FROM return_values_sp;
```